# asp.net membership - how do i create admin versus member role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

i am using the asp.net membership that ships with asp.net-mvc sample app.  how do i set certain users up as an Admin role versus a regular Member role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the way is like Asp.NET WebForms:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(User.Identity.Name, selectedRole)
```

Take a look here http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/util/srcview.aspx?path=~/aspnet/samples/security/Add_Delete_UserRoles.src and here http://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/security/membership.aspx for samples.